# How to define a response type for an async array of objects using .NET

Tags: c#, .net

(this is very simple. I'm new to C#) I'm trying to make a controller/route that sends an HTTP request to an API endpoint and then returns the response of that API to the front end.

```
 public class CarController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public async IAsyncEnumerable<Models.CarModel> Get()
        {
            var host = new HostBuilder()
                .ConfigureServices(services =>
                {
                    services.AddHttpClient();
                    services.AddTransient<Services.CarService>();
                })
                .Build();
            
            var carService = host.Services.GetRequiredService<Services.CarService>();
            yield return await carService.GetCarDetailsAsync(); // Error here*
        }
...
```

- The error prints: `Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error   CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<BupaApi.Models.CarModel>' to 'BupaApi.Models.CarModel'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)  BupaApi C:\Users\User\source\repos\BupaTest\BupaApi\Controllers\CarController.cs    41  Active`

So I think I need to change my `public async IAsyncEnumerable<Models.CarModel> Get()` line to match the response value, but I don't know to find out what this is?

Comment: What return type is the carService.GetCarDetailsAsync()? Theres a mismatch between the controllers return type Enumerable<Models.CarModel> and the return type for the carService.GetCarDetailsAsync()

Comment: You were exactly right Daniel. Thanks. I hadn't realised I could just mirror the return type of the function in my service class.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to return type of `Task<T>` for async method.
In you scenario it will be something like this.

```
public class CarController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IAsyncEnumerable<Models.CarModel>> Get()
        {
            var host = new HostBuilder()
                .ConfigureServices(services =>
                {
                    services.AddHttpClient();
                    services.AddTransient<Services.CarService>();
                })
                .Build();
            
            var carService = host.Services.GetRequiredService<Services.CarService>();
            return await carService.GetCarDetailsAsync(); // Error here*
        }
```

And... as a side note here, you can add the required services in the `startup.cs` and directly inject the dependency into the constructor of the class, so that you could have something like this.

```
public class CarController : ControllerBase
{
        private readonly ICarService _carService;

        public CarController(ICarService carService){
            _carService = carService;
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IAsyncEnumerable<Models.CarModel>> Get()
        {
         //omit for brevity
        }
}
```

Comment: That's it! So simple once you know. For some reason I also had to swap `yield return await carService.GetCarDetailsAsync();` out for `var apiResponse = await carService.GetCarDetailsAsync(); return apiResponse;` as well.

Thanks for your help. Saved me hours probably!

Comment: @JimmyTheCode one more thing, are you going to return `IEnumerable` from the `GetCarDetailsAsync` method? If that's the case, the ,method signature should be `IEnumerable` instead of `IAsyncEnumerable`